# Swap two arrays without using `@tmp`

Tags: arrays, perl, swap

It is very simple to swap two scalar values like:

```
($ours, $theirs) = ($theirs, $ours);
```

Then, how should I do this with array variables?

```
# (@ours, @theirs) = (@theirs, @ours);  # XXX

# lame
my @tmp = @ours;
@ours = @theirs;
@theirs = @tmp;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl flattens all lists, and list assignment is greedy, so you can never assign to `(@ours, @theirs)` and expect `@theirs` to get anything. To put it another way... You can't pass an 'array' to a subroutine. Subroutines in Perl can only receive a list of 0 or more scalars.

You could swap the individual (scalar) elements of the array inside a loop, but this assumes both arrays are of equal length

```
for my $i (0 .. $#ours) {
    ( $ours[$i], $theirs[$i] ) = ( $theirs[$i], $ours[$i] );
}
```

---

Perl 5.22 did introduce an experimental feature called [reference aliasing](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Assigning-to-References) which allows you to assign to a reference. If you are running 5.22 or later, you can enable the experimental feature and then do this.

```
(\@ours, \@theirs) = (\@theirs, \@ours);
```

To enable the feature, and disable the warnings for using an experimental feature, you would do this

```
use v5.22;
use warnings;
use feature 'refaliasing';
no warnings 'experimental::refaliasing';
```

Alternatively, install the [experimental](https://metacpan.org/pod/experimental) module which handles the warnings for you

```
use v5.22;
use warnings;
use experimental 'refaliasing';
```

Answer (score 3):

What about some logic

```
@ar = qw(one two three four);
@br = (1..5);
unshift(@ar,@br);
@br = splice(@ar,scalar @br);
print "@ar\n@br\n";
```

Array swapping is not possible because of the flattening. `(@ar,@br)=(@br,@ar)`

Actually you are creating new list those elements coming from two arrays. Finally you have the one list. That the list data are gone to the first array (@ar). The second array should  be empty (@br).